# Specifying the src path for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum

I'm having issues integrating Ethereum with my website.

1) The following scripts specify the files I need. The file being changed is yourCouncil.html and the files we I need are in dirs bignumber and dist.

```
root@cloud-vm-45-149:/data/project/first_mvp/poll/templates/poll# ls
#about.html#       connection.html       council_login.html~  img                logout.html~         thankYou.html
about.html         connection.html~      councilView.html     landingPage.html   old_files            thankYou.html~
about.html~        contractorView.html   dist                 landingPage.html~  #rating.html#        to_integrate
bignumber          contractorView.html~  feedback.html        login_style1.css   survey_details.html  yourCouncil.html
#connection.html#  council_login.html    feedback.html~       logout.html        survey.html          yourCouncil.html~
root@cloud-vm-45-149:/data/project/first_mvp/poll/templates/poll# emacs yourCouncil.html
```

The code to include these is

```
<!-- web3 scripts -->
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="dist/web3-light.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="bignumber/bignumber.js"></script>
```

The error message is

```
Not found: /your_council/dist/web3-light.js
Not found: /your_council/bignumber/bignumber.js
```

I'm finding it strange because the error message shows a path different from the one I specified.

2) Since  I tried integrating Ethereum, it appears that the JavaScript code isn't being executed in its entirety. I included the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://146.169.45.149:9002"));
    var mining = web3.eth.mining;
    document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = "Test";

</script>


</body>
```

The 
`document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = "Test";` is not working. It refers to

```
<p id="Mining"></p>
```

I found this to be strange as well.
I found that if I change the `document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = "Test";` to be the first line in the script tag, it works.

I'm using Firefox.
If anyone can shed some light on this, would be appreciated.

SOLVED: I'm using Django. Moving the js files into my static folder and referencing them at '/static/bignumber.js' solved the issue.

Comment: You're missing a slash at the beginning of your script references. Adding that tells the browser to look at the root of the *site*, not the page. So it should be `<script src="/dist/scripts.js" ... >`.

Comment: Also, to answer your second question... if the scripts aren't being found, then you couldn't expect them to be executed. If these are different situations, you should separate them into their own question posts.

Comment: Thanks - this sent me in the right direction. I should have added that I'm using Django - moving the files into my static folder and referencing them from the root of the site fixed the issue.

Comment: I think the second issue is related to where I've installed the web3 module in Django so will separate that out into a different post. Thanks again!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question so its marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I'm using Django. Moving the js files into my static folder and referencing them at '/static/bignumber.js' solved the issue.